# Create a oldstyle popup

Tags: html, popup

I know Popup are annoying and they should rarely be use.

But I have for a project the need that when you click on a link a new little window open, not a tab a little window a Pop Up I tried all the Target possible but I fall short. I don't want a overlay, model or something like this cause this I know how to do with css and JS. I need a new separate window.

Do you have any idea?

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_link_target

Comment: @Sko this open a new tab not a popup (I know target blanck)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try the old and gold javascript with

```
   var myWindow = window.open("", "", "width=200, height=100");
```

yeah... Is that simple.

You can look for more here: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_open.asp

Let me know if it helps...

Comment: I tried on Firefow and Chrome and it open a new tab

Comment: Did you set the width and height? Without it should not work.

here: look a sample code: 


`<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<script>
function myFunction() {
    window.open("http://www.google.com", "", "width=200, height=100");
}
</script>`

Comment: @Grabriel  your a genius